# Trying to compile gensort.scala, getting: [error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode =net.java.dev.jets3t#jets3t;0.6.1

Tags: scala, sbt

New to scala and sbt, not sure how to proceed. Am I missing more dependencies?

Steps to reproduce:

1. save gensort.scala code in ~/spark-1.3.0/project/
2. begin build: my-server$ ~/spark-1.3.0/project/sbt
3. > run

gensort.scala: 
[gensort source](https://github.com/rxin/spark/blob/adcae69145905162fa3b6932f70be2c932f95f87/examples/src/main/scala)

build definition file in ~/spark-1.3.0/project/build.sbt:

```
        lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
      settings(
      name := "gensort",
      version := "1.0",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-examples_2.10" % "1.1.1",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.3.0",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11" % "1.3.0",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.3.0",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-network-common_2.10" % "1.2.0",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-network-shuffle_2.10" % "1.3.0",
     "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
)
```

Greatly appreciate any insight on how to move forward. Thx! -Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mix 2.10 and 2.11, they are not binary compatible. Your `libraryDependencies` should look like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-examples" % "1.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-mqtt" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-network-common" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-network-shuffle" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
)
```

The `%%` means that the Scala version is added as a suffix to the library id. After this change I got an error, because a dependency could not be found. It is located here:

```
resolvers += "poho" at "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases"
```

Nevertheless, it seems that `spark-examples` is not available for 2.11. Changing the `scalaVersion` to

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
```

solved all dependency problems and compilation succeeded successfully.

Comment: Worked our great, thanks for your expertise! -Dennis

Comment: @DennisIgnacio if an answer answers your question, you should accept it in order to show others that you are interested in getting answers.